# How to clear submitted php form data with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I attempting to make the form data that was submitted from the form
     be cleared once the clear button is clicked. Now, it clears, refreshes the 
     page then the submitted data reappears. All of this code is in "index.php"
     which the action is set to.

```
<div class="formData" id="formData">
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['age'],))
{
   if(!isset($_SESSION['inputs']))
    {

      $_SESSION['inputs'] = array();
    }
      $_SESSION['inputs'][] = $_POST;

      foreach($_SESSION['inputs'] as $input)
     {

    echo " <span class='trip'> {$input['name']} <br> {$input['age']} <br> 
 </span>";

 }



 }
  ?>
  </div>
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age">
  <button id="clear"> Clear</button> 

</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#clear").click(function()
  {
      $("#formData").empty();
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: You're not directly setting the fields, so it shouldn't populate those fields. Is your browser autocompleting?

Comment: Yeah , it autocompletes. @JoshS.

Comment: I mean, is the browser itself populating it and not php? for instance in chrome, chrome turns the fields yellow as an indication that it's loading cached data.

Comment: try `$('input').val('')`

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean now. The fields do turn yellow. @JoshS.

Comment: @kylel95 yeah it's chrome then, there has been a numerous amount of workarounds to combat this, but chrome is a virus in that factor and has killed those said workarounds. Best way to make sure it never autocompletes is to salt (add random characters to) the name attributes on the form. So every time the page loads, there's a different name for the fields. you can add the salt to a hidden field with a static name to help find the salted POST variables.

Comment: Did. U checked updated answer

Comment: Yeah, just read it. Thank you. Now I have created a button that hides and shows the form using jquery's on click. However, everytime I click submit on the form it slides down and eventually off the page. Do you know how I may keep it in the same place please? I have the postion:fixed; applied, but that is not working

Comment: @kyle95 if you have another problem, open another question on SO. And I suggest you start accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating the combos so I guess you mean the cache. If you wanna make sure that everything is cleared, the reset button must execute $('input').val(''); to clear every input in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add id on form and use jquery or java script as:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="yourForm">

$("#yourForm").trigger('reset'); //jquery

document.getElementById("yourForm").reset(); //java script
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">


$("#clear").click(function () {
 $("#formData").empty();
});

   

//java script
</script>    //This clears it but when I submit data again all the old info and new info appears, how may I only add the new data to the page after I click Reset? This also happens when I refresh the page

Comment: @kylel95:   $("input[type=text]").val("");

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formData").trigger('reset');
```

This will reset the form data.